No compile error for missing import in standalone Angular component
I'm working with standalone Angular 18 components and ran into an issue.
I have a custom component (FooComponent) that I forgot to import into another standalone component. However, no compile-time error appears when I forget to import the component into the imports array of the standalone component.
Here’s the code:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
    <foo-component [content]="getLinkForCopy()"></foo-component>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
  // Forgot to import FooComponent here
})
export class TestComponent {
  getLinkForCopy() {
    return 'https://example.com';
  }
}

Even though I see some errors in the VS Code editor, there’s no compile-time error, only a runtime error when the application runs. How can I catch such missing imports earlier during compilation?

There should be warnings for this already. Are VS Code and the related Angular extensions up-to-date? (I think this is handled by the "Angular Language Extension" extension which is currently on version 18.2).

Cannot reproduce in stackblitz. Maybe you have activated CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA or NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in your app?

@DM there is error in vs code and webStorm but need compile-time error. yes everything is up to date.

@JSONDerulo I already tried in stackblitz but seems that it handles code differently I tried with vs code and web storm but still no compile time error. Also find this general issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46351

This is different issue, when the selector includes native element and an attribute modifier.

@MatthieuRiegler Thanks for the clarification. TBH I don't know how can I reproduce this issue here as stackblitz has different behaviour than IDEA like vs code and web storm

@AlirezaAhmadi, when you use standalone components you should add in "imports" array the components you use (or the modules a component is declared and exported) Please, read the docs, you can also take a tour about the esenctials if you've not read yet.

@Eliseo I know I need to import it. My question is why it does not complain in compile time when I forgot to import it?

@AlirezaAhmadi, in a file.html you can use any "tag", e.g. you can write <fool></fool> and is a "legal" html. Angular only advice if you write a not legal html or forget define a function

I believe the reason you are not receiving an error here is because you are using an inline template - essentially just a string until run time. If you were to create your HTML in a separate file you would be warned immediately if the component had not been imported in the controller.

No also tried with . Html file still the same error
